# iOS NSMutableURLRequest Authorization Header

Tags: ios, ruby, swift, alamofire

I am having trouble accessing an API call and I think it has something to do with the authorization header. I am using AlamoFire and printing out the token so I know it is valid.

```
var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {
    let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString + path)!
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue

    println(Router.OAuthToken)
    if let token = Router.OAuthToken {
        mutableURLRequest.setValue("Token token=\(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    }

    println(mutableURLRequest)

    switch self {
    default:
        return mutableURLRequest
    }
}
```

This is what the documentation says and it works right in the terminal with the auth token:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" http://10x.xx.xx.xxx/api/v1/users/feed
```

Here is the error I'm receiving:

```
Optional(Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.alamofire.error error -1.)")

import Foundation
import Alamofire
import CoreData

enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    static let baseURLString = "http://104.131.81.230/api/v1"
    static var OAuthToken: String?

    case UserProfile
    case FacebookAuth(String)
    case Classes

    var method: Alamofire.Method {
        switch self {
        case .UserProfile:
            return .POST
        case .FacebookAuth:
            return .POST
        case .Classes:
            return .POST
        }
    }

    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case UserProfile:
            return "/users/me"
        case FacebookAuth(let fbAuthToken):
            return "/authentications/?access_token=\(fbAuthToken)"
        case Classes:
            return "/classes/"
        }
    }

    var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {
        let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString + path)!
        let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
        mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue

        println(Router.OAuthToken)
        if let token = Router.OAuthToken {
            println("got token")

            mutableURLRequest.setValue("Token token=<\(token)>", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        }

        println(mutableURLRequest)

        switch self {
        default:
            return mutableURLRequest
        }
    }
}

Alamofire.request(Router.Classes).validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 300).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (request, response, JSON, error) in
        println(JSON)
        println(error)
        if let _json = JSON as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
            println(_json)
            for json in _json {

            }
        }
    })
```

This is the Alamofire request being print out using debugPrintln(), I am getting a 404 error.

```
    $ curl -i \
        -X POST \
        -H "Authorization: Token token=f804414300d84a929b7cec4148fcfd7f" \
        -H "Accept-Language: en;q=1.0,fr;q=0.9,de;q=0.8,zh-Hans;q=0.7,zh-Hant;q=0.6,ja;q=0.5" \
        -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,compress;q=0.5" \
        -H "User-Agent: xxx/com.xxx.xxxx (1; OS Version 8.4 (Build 12H141))" \
"http://10X.XXX.XX.XX/api/v1/classes/"
```

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code snippet where you actually make the request and validate the response? There are a bunch of tricks here to debug your issue, but we should start off with the full code snippet.

Comment: @cnoon i added the rest of the code to the edit, let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are most likely getting a 401 response from the server which is causing the status code validation to fail. I would suggest printing out the `response` that you are receiving. Most likely that will show the authentication issue with a 401 status code.

What would be helpful here is for you to use the `debugPrintln(request)` functionality in Alamofire to debug the `cURL` command being generated. I would guess that the Authorization header isn't being assembled quite the way you would expected. You should try the following:

```
let request = Alamofire.request(Router.Classes)
    .responseJSON { request, response, json, error in
        println(request)
        println(response)
        println(json)
        println(error)
    }

debugPrintln(request)
```

This should help you debug why you're most likely getting a 401 response. If you can try this out and get back to me, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Best of luck!

Comment: I updated the main post however I am getting a 404 response. I know this is an error because if I do the  cURL command in terminal I get the correct response from the server.

Comment: Never mind, this is solved, I realized the endpoint was GET and not POST. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Of course...if you feel the answer helped you out, would you mind uprooting and marking as the answer?